# Некоторые сайты потребляют много ресурсов

Tags: браузер, веб-сайт

Заметил, что некоторые сайты, например cyberforum, при входе на него начинают сильно отжирать ресурсы ноутбука (процессор потребляется почти в 100%, кулер начинает сильнее работать и.т.д.). До конца не могу понять с чем это связано?
Правильные ли у меня предположения, что это происходит из-за выполняемого на моём ноутбуке специфического JS-скрипта, который был отправлен в мой браузер с этого сайта, что и вызвало нагрузку на железо?

Comment: Для неавторизованных пользователей (без логина) загружается версия сайта просто адски перегруженная рекламой. Она жрет кучу ресурсов на слабых компах. Кстати это единственно правильный ответ. Совершенно зря мой ответ был удален. Я специально проверил на слабом компе этот сайт зайдя туда без логина (но с включенным adblock - иначе просмотр сайта превращается просто в ужас) - процессор ушел в 90% загрузку.  А принятый ответ описывает только общую ситуацию без учета специфики конкретного сайта типа cyberforum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипты сайтов обычно не настолько требовательные, чтобы это мешало работе.

Запустите [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) в консоли хрома и проверьте какой этап самый проблемный. Возможно вычислите какие-то аномальные места. Может подцепили майнер и он так маскируется, или какое-нибудь расширение браузера.

Также такое поведение бывает у флеш-баннеров. Но они у многих давно заблокированы или вырезаются адблоком.

Посмотрел упомянутый cyberforum, там всё очень быстро, и такие форумы обычно на сервере всё делают, а не браузер нагружают.